# Drupal 6 and file upload problems

Tags: files

We have an old site running Drupal 6. When we try to upload a file via the interface, the ajax uploader spins, and reloads the "Choose file" dialogue.
Checking the recent error log I get:

```
The file upload failed: field_small_banner_0
```

If I go into the location URL (?q=filefield/ahah/gallery/field_gallery_image/0) I get:

```
{ "data": "\x3cdiv class=\"messages error\"\x3e\nAn unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (64 MB) that this server supports.\x3c/div\x3e\n" }
```

I've seen mentions of ModSecurity but this is not active. I've checked the permissions of the files folder and this is 777.

I've checked phpinfo for the temp folder and that's set to /tmp

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file? The error msg says you likely exceeded the 64MB limit. Can you upload a 1MB file?

If you can upload a 1MB file, then your solution is going to be to increase the server limits on max upload size (see your php.ini file) to allow files of the required size to be uploaded.